# Highcarts - Update a specific categorys values

Tags: javascript, laravel, dynamic, highcharts, updating

In a laravel project, I'm using Highcharts to show a chart of the standard column type simply called column. xAxis has 4 categories representing teams, and yAxis holds each teams score. It looks like this:

```
<div id="chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var chart1 = Highcharts.chart('chart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'title'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ["f","j","n","s"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total score'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
});
</script>
```

The points are added after the page is loaded by using jquery and a javascript function like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    @foreach($existingScores as $score)
        addScoreToChart({!! $score !!})
    @endforeach

});  

function addScoreToChart(obj)
{   
    var scores = obj.params.scores;                  
    var datas = [];    

    for(var k in scores){                
        datas.push([k, parseInt(scores[k])]);      
    }   

    console.log(datas);

    chart1.addSeries({
        name: obj.clientName,
        data: datas,
    });
}
```

This works fine on the initial load of the scores. Some scores will be added to the chart after the page is loaded (via websockets).

I'm quite unsure how to actually update a given teams score. The websockets part is working, and when a new score is added i can call a javascript function that updates the scoreboard with the new data. How can i do this ? Say for example that a new score of 5 points for team "j" is added. How would i tell Highcharts to update the chart with such data / add 5 points to "j" existing score?

Comment: Just as a note, including example data or a working example is really helpful. I created some gibberish data in my answer, but normally I wouldn't bother to answer at all if there is not a working example. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`series.update`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update) to update a series, this function will merge the input with the existing series. Can be done like this:

```
function updateTeam(obj) {
  let name = obj.params.name;
  let scores = obj.params.scores;
  let datas = [];

  for (let k in scores) {
    datas.push([parseInt(k), parseInt(scores[k])]);
  }
  let tmpSeries = chart.series;
  for (var i = 0; i < tmpSeries.length; i++) {
    if (tmpSeries[i].name == name ) {
      tmpSeries[i].update({
        data: datas
      }, true);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'title'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["f", "j", "n", "s"]
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total score'
    },
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    x: -30,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
    borderColor: '#CCC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadow: false
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'team1',
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    },
    {
      name: 'team2',
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }, {
      name: 'team3',
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }
  ]
});

function updateTeam(obj) {
 let name = obj.params.name;
  let scores = obj.params.scores;
  let datas = [];

  for (let k in scores) {
    datas.push([parseInt(k), parseInt(scores[k])]);
  }
  let tmpSeries = chart.series;
  for (var i = 0; i < tmpSeries.length; i++) {
    if (tmpSeries[i].name == name ) {
      tmpSeries[i].update({
        data: datas
      }, true);
    }
  }
}

// the button handler
$('#button').click(function() {
  var incomingObj = {
    params: {
      name: 'team1',
      scores: [2.1, 5.6, 150.4, 99.9]
    }
  };
  updateTeam(incomingObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button" class="autocompare">Update Series</button>
```

**Working JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/Lrxu5u68/2/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redraw the chart as far as I can remember highcharts wont watch the data to draw.

Call `chart.redraw()` when new data comes in from your web socket.

Comment: This is not the issue actually. I have not done this before, and i can get the chart to update without using redraw(); but i just don't know how to add a given score to a specific category (team). When i call the addScoreToChart() function via the websocket, it just adds the score to the first team